# nodejs file2 access and assign value to a variable from file1 and once value is assigned value can use back in file1

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a program in nodejs.
I have a file1.js and file2.js file1.js has a variable which is exported and to get assign value from file2.js so this value can be used here in file1.js.

> file1.js

```
// user given value
let value;

// exporting 
module.exports  = value
```

value I want to use here in file1.js once access and assigned from file2.js

> file2.js

```
const value = require("./file1");

// Give a value
value = 5
```

but its not working what should I do I tried to search example but not able to understand
also I don't want to create this variable in file2.js because I don't want to export from file2.js.

help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

file2.js

```
let value;

const setValue = (v) => {
  value = v;
};

const getValue = () => {
  return value;
};

module.exports = { setValue, getValue };
```

file1.js

```
const { setValue, getValue } = require("./file1");

setValue(5);
console.log(getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because you are using const, however, you should use let here.

```
let value = require("./file1");

// Give a value
value = 5;
console.log(value); // 5
```

Node imports are always Singleton and have the caching mechanism. So, this value will be shared in all the imports.